# django + mongodb + gridfs - 'str' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, django, mongodb, gridfs

I am attempting to get mongodb + gridfs working for django so that I can serve files out of django, but upon programmatically creating a new file, I get this error.  I'm not sure which documents to follow as it appears some of them are out of date.

Here is my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'files': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'files',
        'USER': 'files',
        'PASSWORD': 'files',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 27017,
        'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': False,
    }
}


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'mongo_storage.storage.GridFSStorage'
GRIDFS_DATABASE = 'files'
```

And, in my model, I'm simply using a file field:

```
data = models.FileField(upload_to="/tmp/uploads")
```

Then, I'm creating a new file ...:

```
internal_file = File()
internal_file.data.save(checksum, open(path).read())
```

That is when I get the attribute error.

Do I need to configure my model differently, not call the save() method explicitly?

Comment: You need to wrap your content in ContentFile, or wrap the file handler in a Django File object when calling save(). Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7515224/1530272

Comment: I tried that before and again, I get this error: value too long for type character varying(32).  I'm not sure if that is a positive step or a side step.

Comment: positive step: the path you're uploading to has to be less than 32 chars according to your db constraint. either up the max charsize on the file name field, or use a shorter file name

Comment: Hi Sohan, is that for the mongodb name field or what?  I tried changing my constraints for the model as well as changing the filename itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just had to do this:

image.data.save(image.checksum, File(open(path)))

Prior to doing that, I was just passing in a regular python file which was the problem.