# Save a writable file into database?

Tags: python, django, file-io

I am using django 1.8 and python 3.4 and trying to create a json file and then writing into it, after that I need to save it to my database but on save it returns me an error '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute '_committed'. Can anyone please help where I am doing wrong?
Here is my models.py

```
class ConvertedFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='json/upload', max_length=5000)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My views.py is-

```
def convert_file(request):
    url = request.GET.get('q', None)
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open('file.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
    csvfile = open("file.csv", "r")
    jsonfile = open("file.json", "w")
    csv_rows = []
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    title = reader.fieldnames
    try:
        for row in reader:
            csv_rows.extend([{title[i]: row[title[i]] for i in range(len(title))}])
    except:
        pass

    jsonfile.write(json.dumps(csv_rows, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False))

    os.remove("file.csv")
    jsonfile.close()

    new_json = ConvertedFile.objects.create()
    new_json.file = jsonfile
    new_jsone.save()
```

Comment: maybe unrelated but you have to close `csvfile` before removing it. for instance that would crash on windows.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks and any suggestion to overcome with my issue?

Comment: Jsonfile is a closed file. You are passing it to your new_json object. It is not of the proper type and even if it was it is a closed file.

Comment: Don't save files in a database.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829952/267540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error raises on `model.save()` in the last line, right? The line above `new_json.file = jsonfile` is the problem. You pass the reference to a closed (plain python) file object to the FileField from django and it does not know how to deal with it (`_commited` is missing for example).

Have a look at [Django - how to create a file and save it to a model's FileField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514964/django-how-to-create-a-file-and-save-it-to-a-models-filefield)