# Django model current link not pointing to file in MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: python, django

My code generates Pandas dataframes. They are big. I save them as files. For this, I have created this `Model`:

**models.py:**

```
class TargetFiles(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    csv_file = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='target')
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**settings.py:**

```
...
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**mycode.py:**

```
file_content = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')
csvname = 'target1.csv'
csf = ContentFile(file_content, csvname)
TargetFiles.objects.create(owner=self.user, csv_file=csf, file_name=csvname)
```

**urls.py (project):**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('dataapp/', include('dataapp.urls')),
]
```

**urls.py (dataapp):**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='dataapp'),
    path('welcome/', views.welcome_dataapp, name='welcome_dataapp'),
    path('download/<str:file_name>', views.download, name='download'),
]
```

I don't know if this is the best approach for the problem. This [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) made me skeptical. The thing is that my code is generating the file properly, and saving it in the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory. But when I go to admin view and click on `TargetFiles` object, the link to the file returns this error:

The current path, `media/target/target1.csv`, didn't match any of these.

Since I am not an Django expert, I think I am setting something wrong. Maybe in settings.py or in urls.py (in this file I didn't write any reference to media, maybe this is where the error lives).

I have already read these posts:
[Django - how to create a file and save it to a model's FileField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514964/django-how-to-create-a-file-and-save-it-to-a-models-filefield?rq=1)
,
[Django: generate a CSV file and store it into FileField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749756/django-generate-a-csv-file-and-store-it-into-filefield?noredirect=1&lq=1) and this [assign resulting csv file to django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765879/assign-resulting-csv-file-to-django-model?noredirect=1&lq=1). But I was not able to make the admin link point to the `MEDIA_ROOT` file.

Does anyone have ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your urls.py

Comment: I have updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: Try editing your app urlpatterns in the urls.py like: urlpatterns = [ ... your paths ... ]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) and try if it's working.

Comment: I tried this, Django is showing the same error message.

Comment: See it already works for you and you already accepted another answer, so no point for me to add an answer as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does not serve the files stored in the `MEDIA_ROOT`. You can enable this *during development* by adding the following to your root url config:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

It's recommended to let file serving be handled by some other server (apache or nginx) whe deploying to a production server.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this solution, but it keeps me returning the same error message. Do you have any clue what it's possibly happening?

Comment: Did you reload Django after changing `urls.py` and is `DEBUG` set to `True` in `settings.py`? Also, make sure you've added this to the root `urls.py` (the project one) not the one in `dataapp`.

Comment: Yes, I have reloaded and set DEBUG=True.

Comment: Could you post the full error text of the `The current path, media/target/target1.csv, didn't match any of these.` message? Django usually lists the available url patterns, so there might be a clue there.

Comment: It worked. I had changed the wrong urls.py. Sorry and thanks again.