# assign resulting csv file to django model

Tags: python, html, django, csv, midi

I'm developing a website that consists of different songs. These songs contain different attributes, one of them is a midi file that I upload through the fileField field of django. When I add a song with these attributes using a form, I call a script that generates a csv file with midi attribute information.

The problem is that I would like to assign this resulting csv file directly to another Filefield, i.e. when I create the form, this csv is assigned to a fileField, just after submitting the form.

I'd like to know if somebody could please help me with this. If you need any code or something else let me know.

Here's my code at forms.py. With this form, I add a new song with the following atributes.

```
class FormCancion(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Cancion
    fields= ['titulo','creacion','midi','dificultad','nota_pad_verde','nota_pad_gris','nota_pad_azul','nota_pad_amarillo','nota_pad_rojo']
```

views.py code. This view is used to call the form that will add the new song.

```
def crearCancion(request):

cancion=Cancion()
if request.method=="POST":
    formulario=FormCancion(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=cancion)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
        subprocess.call(['python', '/home/josema/MEGA/Universidad/Universidad/PROYECTO/MIDIPIRCUSSION/MIDIPIRCUSSION_APP/static/MIDIPIRCUSSION_APP/parser.py', '/home/josema/MEGA/Universidad/Universidad/PROYECTO/MIDIPIRCUSSION/media/'+str(cancion.midi)])
        return redirect('/ListadoCanciones/')
else:
    formulario=FormCancion()
    context={'formulario':formulario}
    return render(request,"nuevaCancion.html",context)
```

My models.py code. The only model field that I need to add is the csv file. I'd like to add it automatically after I submit the form.

```
class Cancion(models.Model):

    titulo=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    creacion=models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    avanzado="Avanzado"
    intermedio="Intermedio"
    principiante="Principiante"
    dificultades=((avanzado, 'Avanzado'), (intermedio, 'Intermedio'), (principiante, 'Principiante'))
    dificultad=models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=dificultades)

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.midi.path
    midi = models.FileField()

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.csv.path
    csv = models.FileField()
```

Comment: please elaborte more, how your model and form look like?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514964/django-how-to-create-a-file-and-save-it-to-a-models-filefield ? I think it is what you want

Comment: I updated the post with my code. Let me know if you need something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a model like this,

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):

    doc = models.FileField(upload_to='media/', null=True, blank=True)
```

then do something like this to add file to model,

```
from django.core.files import File

myfile = open("sample.csv", 'r')
sample = SampleModel.objects.create(doc=File(myfile))
```

**UPDATE**

```
from django.core.files import File

myfile = open("sample.csv", 'r')
sample = Cancion.objects.create(csv=File(myfile))
```

Comment: That's more less what I want, but It doesnt work at all. I only want to add one file, only the fileField atribute of the model

Comment: Yeah... Updated the answer.. Please hqve a look

Comment: I think it is not exactly want I want. This adds a new model with all the atributes. Most of the atributes are added by a form, but after I submit the form is when I need to assign the file to the model field. I updated the post with my code.

Comment: @Josema_23 could you fix the indentations ?

Comment: How do you get the data required to create the csv?

Comment: I have a parser.py file, that receives a midi file, extracts some information, creates the csv file and saves the information in the csv file. This parser.py file is called in the preceding view.

Comment: Then whats the problem ? I don't understand :(

Comment: I used your solution, and it adds a new model with the atributes that I add in SampleModel.objects.create(doc=File(myfile)). What I need is to add this csv file to the model that is created by the form. Sorry if I don't explain it really well :(

Comment: I don't mean you create a **new model**. I used a sentence as ***Assuming you have a model like this***.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works. It was my problem, I was not doing it in the correct place of the code.