# django model FileField is not storing database

Tags: python, django

```
  from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

  fs_photo = FileSystemStorage(location='/media/photos')
  fs_files = FileSystemStorage(location='/media/files')
 # this method i tried
 offer_letter = models.FileField(storage=fs_files,null=True)
 appraisal_letter = models.FileField(storage=fs_files,null=True)

#this method 
resume = models.FileField(upload_to='resume/',null=True)

#this method also i tried to save
offer_letter = 
models.FileField(upload_to='media/',blank=True,null=True)
# media path
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
MEDIA_URL ="/media/"
# in urls.py 

          ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

i am trying to save a file to database but its not saving and my media paths are also perfect.please help me out for this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - how to create a file and save it to a model's FileField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514964/django-how-to-create-a-file-and-save-it-to-a-models-filefield)

Comment: its saving to database after adding this enctype="multipart/form-data" in forms