# Uploaded csv in Django not saving

Tags: django, csv

The only purpose of this project is to show an uploaded csv on the template from the template. It works. But when I restart the server or even if I just refresh the page, the uploaded csv data disappears. The request handling was not passing any data to the template via context.

My views.py is:

```
import csv, io
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Table

def data_upload(request):
    template = "home.html"

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, template)

    csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'Please upload a .csv file.')

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
        _, created = Table.objects.update_or_create(
            page=column[0], 
            keyword=column[1], 
            interval=column[2], 
            email=column[3], 
            notes=column[4], 
            billing=column[5],
        )
    context = {
        'tables': Table.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The template upload form is:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="file-field input-field">
<div class="btn">
    <span>Upload a CSV FILE</span>
    <input type="file" name="file">
</div>
<div class="file-path-wrapper">
    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
</div>
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn teal" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
```

I know I need a .save() somewhere, and I've tried it but it doesn't work.

Anyone?

Comment: Your get request handling is not passing anything to the template via context.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm able to show data on the template when I upload the csv file.

Comment: Yes but as you say when you refresh you get nothing, because you are not passing the Table objects when request is GET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - how to create a file and save it to a model's FileField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514964/django-how-to-create-a-file-and-save-it-to-a-models-filefield)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mehran mentioned you are not passing 'tables' context during GET request. that's why you are getting data in POST and not GET.

```
import csv, io
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Table

def data_upload(request):
    template = "home.html"


    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_file = request.FILES['file']
        if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            messages.error(request, 'Please upload a .csv file.')

        data_set = csv_file.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
        next(io_string)
        for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
            _, created = Table.objects.update_or_create(
                page=column[0], 
                keyword=column[1], 
                interval=column[2], 
                email=column[3], 
                notes=column[4], 
                billing=column[5],
            )
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        # DO something in GET call
        pass
    context = {
        'tables': Table.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Aha. so it should've been POST, not GET. Thanks!